# AppServ phpmyadmin #2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, appserv

estoy teniendo problemas para acceder a mysql a través de phpmyadmin. Nunca había tenido problemas, pero de la nada cuando intento conectarme me salta el siguiente error:

```
#2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. <br />El servidor no está respondiendo (o el zócalo local al servidor MySQL no está configurado correctamente).
```

Foto:

[image: Este es el error]

Debajo me aparece esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien tiene alguna idea de como solucionar este problema? Porque anduve buscando y las soluciones que encontré como borrar el `ib_logfile0` y `ib_logfile1`, o cambiar el puerto 3306 por algún otro no dieron resultado.

Comment: Checa esta forma http://www.espaciolinux.com/foros/programacion/configurar-socket-del-servidor-mysql-t32850.html

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Hace 20 minutos que había probado la solución justo de esa página y me olvidé de cerrar la pregunta. Con cambiar "cookie" por "http" se solucionó el problema! Gracias nuevamente! Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como explica en [una respuesta de este foro](https://www.espaciolinux.com/foros/programacion/configurar-el-socket-del-servidor-mysql-t32850.html?sid=d1f8b8e9f4c00d76613818b1511e2122#p155775), la manera de solucionarlo es:

1. En la carpeta de *phpmyadmin* (`/etc/phpmyadmin` en Linux por ejemplo), si se tiene el archivo `config.inc.php` seguir al siguiente paso, si no, buscar el archivo `config.sample.inc.php` y renombralo por `config.inc.php`
2. Abrir ese archivo y en la linea 30 que dice:

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';`

Cambiarlo por:

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';`

Al entrar otra vez te pide el login y password, si no lo has modificado el login es root y el password lo dejas en blanco